# FFMPEG failing to convert mov to flv

Tags: ffmpeg

FFMPEG issue that I am not familiar with. seems to only happen with this particular file. Anyone by any chance can take a look at this long out put and provide any feedback on what might actually be causing this?

```
ffmpeg_18.exe -i "E:\TESTFILES\115637.mov" -vcodec libx264 -b:v 700k -s 720x480 -r 29.97 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf yadif -aspect 4:3 -acodec libvo_aacenc -b:a 96k -ar 44100 -f mp4 -y "E:\TESTFILES\test\115637.flv"
ffmpeg version N-39877-g4fa706a Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 16 2012 14:53:47 with gcc 4.6.3
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libcelt --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-li
bnut --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libutvideo --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      51. 46.100 / 51. 46.100
  libavcodec     54. 14.101 / 54. 14.101
  libavformat    54.  3.100 / 54.  3.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 70.100 /  2. 70.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0. 11.100 /  0. 11.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'E:\TESTFILES\115637.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2018-05-03 20:48:28
  Duration: 00:00:30.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 154663 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 151585 kb/s, SAR 1920:1920 DAR 16:9, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 60k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-03 20:48:28
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 48000 Hz, 4 channels, s16, 3072 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-03 20:48:28
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-03 20:51:29
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00;00
[buffer @ 035c33a0] w:1920 h:1080 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/1000000 sar:1920/1920 sws_param:flags=2
[yadif @ 01e7caa0] mode:0 parity:-1 auto_enable:0
[scale @ 01e7c6a0] w:1920 h:1080 fmt:yuv420p sar:1920/1920 -> w:720 h:480 fmt:yuv420p sar:32/27 flags:0x4
[libx264 @ 035b8c40] using SAR=8/9
[libx264 @ 035b8c40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2 AVX FMA3
[libx264 @ 035b8c40] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 035b8c40] 264 - core 120 r2164 da19765 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2012 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,
11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=24 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitra
te=700 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[libvo_aacenc @ 01e7bae0] Unable to set encoding parameters
Output #0, mp4, to 'E:\TESTFILES\test\115637.flv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2018-05-03 20:48:28
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264, yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 700 kb/s, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-03 20:48:28
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, 4 channels, s16, 96 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-03 20:48:28
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le -> libvo_aacenc)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Comment: In case you are facing this issues just with a single file, then try to convert that file with some other converter, say `Format Factory` or anything you want. I once faced such issues but later I found the problem was with the file itself. If it is same for all the mov files or other converters are working then the problem is not with the file but in your code. Just suggesting, if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Your `ffmpeg` is really old

You can get a recent version for Windows at [Zeranoe](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

## libvo_aacenc is crappy

It was removed from `ffmpeg` years ago. Quality was bad and it could not handle more than 2 channels. Update and use the built-in AAC encoder instead:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium -vf "yadif,scale=-2:720,format=yuv420p" -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 96k output.flv
```

- This example downmixes your 4 channel input to 2 channels (stereo) with the `-ac 2` option.
- See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for video encoding info.

Comment: Apparently the Editor decided to go with 4 channels instead of 2 and this caused the issue. had them go with 2 and it works.

Comment: @scripter78 You should still really consider upgrading your `ffmpeg`. As of now your ancient build is behind by 51064 updates.

Comment: I would agree with you if we were keeping this process running for an extended time but right now we should be moving to an entirely new process in the next couple of months and the original developer is no longer here so we are just holding out to move away from it completely instead of possibly breaking something even worse.